# How can I run .exe file from C?

Tags: c

I have created wit_func.exe using Matlab. Now I am trying to run the program using C.
I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int r;
    r=system("C:\\Users\\mails\\OneDrive\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Testing for the executable files\\wit_func.exe");
    printf("%d",r);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I provided the path to that .exe file. I getting this following output:
'C:\Users\mails\OneDrive\Documents\MATLAB\Testing' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1

I also need to pass some integer arguments to this executable file. Can somebody help me run this program properly?

Comment: Since your path contains a space you need to enclose the entire path in quotes as - `"\"C:\\Users\\mails\\OneDrive\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Testing for the executable files\\wit_func.exe\""`

Comment: [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) doesn't return what you appear to think it does.

Comment: Rename `Testing for the executable files` to `Ishallnotusespacesinfilenames` and try again. :-)